# Spark Streaming - Block replication policy issue in case of multiple executor on the same worker

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, executor, apache-spark-standalone

I am running a spark streaming application on a cluster composed by three nodes, each node with a worker and three executors (so a total of 9 executors). I am using Spark version 2.3.2, and the spark standalone cluster manager.

### The problem

Investigating a recent issue when a worker machine completely went down, I could see that the spark streaming job was stopped for the following reason:

```
18/10/08 11:53:03 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 122 in stage 413804.1 failed 8 times; aborting job
```

The job was aborted due to a task in the same stage failing 8 times.
This is the expected behaviour.

The mentioned task failed for the following reason:

```
18/10/08 11:53:03 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 413804 (flatMapToPair at MessageReducer.java:30) failed in 3.817 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 122 in stage 413804.1 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 122.7 in stage 413804.1 (TID 223071001, 10.12.101.60, executor 1): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-39-1539013586600 of RDD 1793044 not found
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 122 in stage 413804.1 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 122.7 in stage 413804.1 (TID 223071001, 10.12.101.60, executor 1): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-39-1539013586600 of RDD 1793044 not found
```

So then I tried to track the not found block input-39-1539013586600 and I can see this:

```
18/10/08 11:46:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-39-1539013586600 in memory on 10.10.101.66:32825 (size: 1398.0 B, free: 5.2 GB)
18/10/08 11:46:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added input-39-1539013586600 in memory on 10.10.101.66:35258 (size: 1398.0 B, free: 5.2 GB)
18/10/08 11:47:35 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for input-39-1539013586600 !
18/10/08 11:53:03 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 122.0 in stage 413804.1 (TID 223070944, 10.10.101.60, executor 5): java.lang.Exception: Could not compute split, block input-39-1539013586600 of RDD 1793044 not found
18/10/08 11:53:03 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 122.1 in stage 413804.1 (TID 223070956) on 10.12.101.66, executor 9: java.lang.Exception (Could not compute split, block input-39-1539013586600 of RDD 1793044 not found) [duplicate 1]
```

As you can notice, the block was replicated on two different executors **on the same worker** (10.10.101.66 in this case).

### Spark code

We then checked spark code to see if this behaviour is normal, and it seems it is.
The default policy used in the BlockManager is RandomBlockReplication (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala#L240).

In this policy, despite the javaDoc saying *"...basic implementation, that just makes sure we put blocks on different hosts, if possible"*, the policy seems completely random, as they are not using the `host` property of the `BlockManagerId` object to try to put the replica on a different host (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockReplicationPolicy.scala#L120).

If our analysis is correct, **it seems that in a configuration like ours (multiple executors in one worker machine) spark stream can go easily down if the whole host is lost.**

Forcing the job to use `BasicBlockReplicationPolicy` does not seem a solution either, as this policy fallback to the random mechanism if no topology is specified (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockReplicationPolicy.scala#L169), and I was not able to find in the code where we can set the topology (this value it seems not to be used for the moment).

### Final questions

- Can we consider this as a bug in Spark?
- Has anyone faced this issue in the past? Is there any workaround available (other than reduce the number of executor per worker to 1)?